# How to display the json representation of a DataTable? GoogleCharts

Tags: javascript, json, django, google-visualization

In its documentation, it says:

> toJSON() |    String |    Returns a string version of the JSON representation of
>   the chart.

Let's say I have created a DataTable and it is stored in data:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

How can I display this in the same manner that the chart is displayed?

The chart is displayed using this line:

```
new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data,
               {title:"S&P 500 Up/Down Performance Since 1980",
                width:600, height:400,
                isStacked:"true",
                bar:{groupWidth: "90%"},
                legend:"none" }
          );
```

Instead of data, I want to display data.toJson().

Any help or direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: did you try `draw(data.toJson(), ....`  ?

Comment: If that works I'm gonna shoot myself for not trying , give me one sec

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
          draw(data.toJson(),
               {title:"S&P 500 Up/Down Performance Since 1980",
                width:600, height:400,
                isStacked:"true",
                bar:{groupWidth: "90%"},
                legend:"none" }
          );
```

Your prolly miss add `toJson()` in your `ColumnChart`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is a really stupid question, I guess I'm tired and need to go to sleep. data.toJSON() returns the string form of the DataTable, all I have to do is document.getElementById("stupid").innerHTML = data.toJSON(); then I can display it in template through the element id. Thanks again, closing question.